# JSON: Parse ArrayNode of Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse a JSON ArrayNode in Java but I'm having some issues.

The object is as follows:

```
{
  "type": "type",
  "id": "id",
  "attributes": {
    "x": [ "x.value" ],
    "y": [ "y.value" ],
    "z": [ "z.value" ]
  }
}
```

I'm parsing it as follows:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> users = new HashMap<>();
Iterator<JsonNode> arrayIterator = dataArray.elements();
while (arrayIterator.hasNext())
{
  JsonNode r = arrayIterator.next();
  String id = r.get("id").asText();
  users.put(id, new HashMap<>());
  Iterator<JsonNode> attributeIterator = r.path("attributes").elements();
  while (attributeIterator.hasNext())
  {
    JsonNode attribute = attributeIterator.next();
    users.get(id).put(attribute.asText(),
            attribute.elements().next().asText());
  }
}
```

But I'm getting a map like this:

```
"" => z.value
```

I found out in Java' documentation that the attribute `.asText()` will return `empty` if it is not a value node. How can I get that name so my map is instead:

```
x => x.value
y => y.value
z => z.value
```

Comment: What version of jackson are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Jackson 2.6.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the first thing you need the keys of your JSON. So I tried with `fields` instead of only `elements`

```
  Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> attributeIterator = dataArray.path("attributes").fields();
            while (attributeIterator.hasNext())
            {
                Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> attribute = attributeIterator.next();
                users.get(id).put(attribute.getKey(),
                        attribute.getValue().get(0).asText());
            }
```

I didn't like to get an array So I change to this

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> attributeIterator = dataArray.path("attributes").fields();
            while (attributeIterator.hasNext())
            {
                Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> attribute = attributeIterator.next();
                users.get(id).put(attribute.getKey(),
                        attribute.getValue().elements().next().textValue());
            }
```

The reason I used `fields` because I needed the key value :

> Iterator that can be used to traverse all **key/value pairs** for object
>   nodes; empty iterator (no contents) for other types

And `elements` doesn't include keys:

> Method for accessing all value nodes of this Node, iff this node is a
>   JSON Array or Object node. In case of Object node, **field names
>   (keys) are not included,** only values. For other types of nodes,
>   returns empty iterator.

From [Java Docs](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#fields())

This is getting the map filled. I used `jackson 2.9.4`

Comment: Had to change code to Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> attributeIterator = r.path("attributes").fields(); following my previous code to make it work but worked like a charm, thanks! Probably need to make that change for posterity.